# How to send kendo ui grid data in email as attachments?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have to send an email, with kendo ui grid data as attachment. If I use excel export the I am not able to auto save the file in project folder at particular location. I am not able to customize the saveAsExcel() method.

So I don't want to save that file in the local folder. Is there any way to do this?

I am not able to auto download the file to specific folder in project. Every time it is asking to save at particular location.

I am trying to auto save the file to specific folder in project and try to attach that file in email.

I am not getting any data in excel while saving grid. Also I want to avoid the save as popup for saving the file.

```
var grid = $("#MyReport").data("kendoGrid");
    var trs = $("#MyReport").find('tr');
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(trs[i]);
        rows.push({
            cells: [

                dataItem

            ]
        })

    }



var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({  
    sheets: [  
      {   title: "EmployeeInfo",  
          rows: rows  
      }  
    ]  
});  
kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: "EmployeeInfo.xlsx" });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on wrong track. In real case scenario, your project should be on server. When a user clicks export on your grid it will be prompted to save on his local computer not in your project on server. Kendo export is client-side export. You need to export on the server-side, save the file on the server and attache it when sending mail through your project.

Steps to take:

1. On export button click send params `page_size` and `page`
2. On server-side with that params get data from a database
3. On server-side with data from a database create a file (excel)
4. On server-side via mail client attache created file and send it

Comment: Thank you. I have followed above steps. It is working.